# How to assign a value to the variable based on the existing variables in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to assign a value to the variable based on the existing variable values.
I will give you a brief explanation of the data.

```
mydata

      category  original_wt  predicted_wt   categorized
    1 xxxxx      2.5          3.0            original
    2 yyyyy      3.5          4.0            predicted
    3 zzzzz      3.0          5.0            predicted
    4 aaaaa      4.0          2.5            original
    5 bbbbb      3.2          5.5            original
    6 ccccc      4.6          3.5            predicted
```

From the above data i want to assign a value based on categorized type.
If it is original the categorized value should be original_wt of same row.
If it is predicted the categorized value should be predicted_wt of same row.

**Expected output:**

```
mydata

  category  original_wt  predicted_wt   categorized   categorized_value
1 xxxxx      2.5          3.0            original      2.5
2 yyyyy      3.5          4.0            predicted     4.0
3 zzzzz      3.0          5.0            predicted     5.0
4 aaaaa      4.0          2.5            original      4.0
5 bbbbb      3.2          5.5            original      3.2
6 ccccc      4.6          3.5            predicted     3.5
```

**Tried:**

```
mydata['categorized_value'] = 
     if mydata['categorized'] == 'original':
        mydata['categorized_value'] = mydata['original_wt']
     else:
     mydata['categorized_value'] = mydata['predicted_wt']
```

How do i get my expected output in python?

Comment: Is the code indented correctly? The else: branch is not indented now and will always be run, so value is always predicted

Comment: What output *do* you get?

Comment: @Tichodroma   invalid syntax! thanks for showing interest.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen indented correctly in terminal but not here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `loc` and a boolean mask to set the values you desire:

```
In [221]:

df.loc[df['categorized'] == 'original', 'categorized_value'] = df['original_wt']
df.loc[df['categorized'] == 'predicted', 'categorized_value'] = df['predicted_wt']
df
Out[221]:
  category  original_wt  predicted_wt categorized  categorized_value
1    xxxxx          2.5           3.0    original                2.5
2    yyyyy          3.5           4.0   predicted                4.0
3    zzzzz          3.0           5.0   predicted                5.0
4    aaaaa          4.0           2.5    original                4.0
5    bbbbb          3.2           5.5    original                3.2
6    ccccc          4.6           3.5   predicted                3.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply`:

```
mydata['categorized_value'] = mydata.apply(lambda x: x['original_wt'] if x['categorized'] == 'original' else x['predicted_wt'], axis=1)
```